# How can I get the output from pynput to somewhere other than the VSCode file?

Tags: python, pynput

I'm new to python (been using it in VSCode) and recently have been working with pynput. I have it set up to type things but (I'm new to programming in general) I can't figure out how I could get that output somewhere else which is not just in the VSCode file.

This could be a really obvious solution, I've just never actually done anything outside of the terminal in terms of programming.

Thank you.

All I have tried is setting up a VSCode python run file shortcut to see if I had my cursor in a different textbar whether or not it would type there. Obviously it did not.

Comment: So you don't want the output to be in the terminal? You want the output to be written to another file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To specify, for example, could the output be written in for example any given search bar (or anywhere the user's cursor currently is).

As in could the user use the script to type something not in the terminal but google for example.